# Two correlated Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

```
I am learning Stochastic Process and there is an exercise I could not figure out.
```

> Let W1 and W2 be two independent Standard Brownian motion.
>
> Take $S_{1,t} = e^{\alpha W_{1,t} + \beta W_{2,t}}$ and $S_{2,t} = e^{\gamma W_{1,t} + \delta W_{2,t}}$.
>
> (1) Find the infinitesimal mean and covariance
>   $$ \alpha(s_1,s_2)dt = \mathbb{E}[(dS_1,dS_2)|S_{1,t}=s_{1},S_{2,t}=s_{2}]$$
>   $$ \mu(s_1,s_2)dt = cov[(dS_1,dS_2)|S_{1,t}=s_{1},S_{2,t}=s_{2}].$$
>
> (2) Is $S_{1,t}$ a one-dimensional Markov process? Is $(S_{1,t},S_{2,t}$) a two dimensional Markov process?

I don't really know how to get started. Since the exponential term basically prevent me from doing the regular calculation...I tried to get started, the following picture is where I got stopped.[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz3Z1.jpg)

And for the part(2), by definition Markov process is "independent increment", But in this case, the S relies on 2 Brownian motion. And there are certain relations between $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$. So I don't know how to think of this question.

Looking forward to someone's help. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

With Ito’s rule,

$$dS_{1,t} = S_{1,t}[\alpha dW_{1,t} + \beta dW_{2,t}
+\frac12 (\alpha^2+\beta^2)dt]$$

$$dS_{2,t} = S_{2,t}[\gamma dW_{1,t} + \delta dW_{2,t}
+\frac12 (\gamma^2+\delta^2)dt]$$

Evaluate,

$$ \mathbb{E}[(dS_1,dS_2)|S_{1,t}=s_{1},S_{2,t}=s_{2}]
=\frac12 ( s_1(\alpha^2+\beta^2), s_2(\gamma^2+\delta^2))dt$$

$$ cov[(dS_1,dS_2)|S_{1,t}=s_{1},S_{2,t}=s_{2}]
=s_1s_2(\alpha\gamma+\beta\delta)dt$$

$S_{1,t}$ is a Markov process, so is $(S_{1,t},S_{2,t})$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. May I ask a further question? I do learn Ito lemma already, but It didn't occur to me that I should use it in this question. So the version I learned is. If there is a function u(Wt,t), Wt is Brownian motion, then du = \partial_W u(Wt,t) dW + (\partial_t+ 1/2 \partial_w^2) u(Wt,t) dt. But here How to apply it to "2 Brownian motion" W1 and W2?

Comment: Oh and by the way, what's the relationship between "being a Markov process" and the expectation to vanish? I was thinking how to show, say E(Xt_n| t1,t2,...t_n-1) = E(Xt_n| t_n-1). Namely it only depends on nearest past.

Comment: The way right now I am thinking is that, 1-dimensional S_{1,t} is not a Markov. Because I have to know both the position of W_{1,t} and W_{2,t}. If I only given S_{1,t}=s1. Then I cannot solve the 1 equation with 2 unknowns. But If we go to 2-dimensional S_{1,t} and S_{2,t}. Then if given both positions S_{1,t}=s1 and S_{2,t}=s2, then I can solve for W_{1,t} and W_{2,t} explicitly. Then can I say the 2-dimensional is Markov? Thanks

Comment: The sum of two independent Brownian motions is still a Brownian motion, with incremental variance given by the sum of the two individual variances.

Comment: If a process is Markovian, it does not display a drift. So, it’s expectation is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think about your statement for a while and still cannot get it. I am stuck to the conditional expectation's definition of Markov process, I don't understand why for it to be a Markov process it cannot display a drift. I am thinking, even for a Brownian motion with drift, it's still a Markov process, am I right here or did I misunderstand it ? say X= B+ct for drift constant c. Then given at time t, X_t= k. Then we can know at time t+delta t, X is a Gaussian with mean k+c*delta t. Could you please help explain a little bit more here about how to determine Markov?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about Martingale property. I believe a geometric Brownian motion has the Markov property.

Comment: Ok. So I am quite sure that the 2-dimension together (S_{1,t} , S_{2,t}) is a Markov process. But is single one S_{1,t} also Markov process? Just as I was thinking before, do I have to be able to determine both position of W1 and W2 then would I be able to claim it's Markov process? Because if only given , say S_{1,t} = s1 at time t. Then we only have exp(a W1 + b W2)= s1. Then we could not figure each individual out. Is my reasoning here correct? Thanks for you patience with me in this question~

Comment: No problem. As I pointed out previously, the sum of two Brownians is still a Briownian, $a dw_1+ b dw_2 = c dw$, where $c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So, you have only one position to determine. $S_1$ is a Markov process.

Comment: Oh right! I understand this finally! Thank you so much!